# Proper way to split big thrift file

Tags: thrift

I got a thrift file which contains tens of structs' definition, and I'm trying to split it to multiple smaller thrift files, so I have a main thrift file which includes other thrift files but only the main file would be compiled, nor the included files, with no error.

My first guess was that's because of no reference from main file to included file since my structs are quite separated. My objective is to compile all the files. So what's the proper way to split a big thrift file like this? (Maybe I was doing something wrong?)

Comment: Your question seems rather unclear. Do you want to know how to split a file or do you just want to compile the already split files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-r` switch ("recurse") when launching the Thrift compiler. This will compile all `included` files too.

Or enter `thrift --help` to view all the options.

Alternatively, you could iterate through all *.thrift files via loop (depends on your OS). This would also do what you want to achieve but may be more cumbersome.